# cpp iterator problem

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<class T>
    class mStack
    {
    private:
       vector<T> a; 
       vector<T>::iterator top;
    public:
       void push(T);
       T pop();
       mStack();
       void printStack();
};
```

The code with above class is not getting compiled... why? What is the problem? The compiler says "expected ; above top".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a typename:

```
typename vector<T>::iterator top;
```

This reassures the compiler thar `vector<T>` really is a type. For a discussion of this and other template gotchas, see the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html).

Comment: Just replace your string with "top" with what Neil suggests.

Comment: I wish that I could write a good, simple explanation for when exactly it's required, but in reality most of the time just adding typename before anything which is a type which uses a template parameter is harmless and works.

Comment: @pete - that's why I refer them to the faq :-)